# How to check how responsive web page looks on tablets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a problem with checking how designed web page will looks on mobil devices like tablet.

I have found online emulators but any of them does not show real look.
On these emulators everything is correct but when I check it on tablet it looks really bad.

I need an easy way to check responsive website look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chrome's built-in device mode emulator.

> Enabling device mode:

- Press F12 on Google Chrome to access the DevTools.
- Turn on device mode by pressing the Phone icon at the top-left corner
  of DevTools.

For more info : [Device Mode & Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)

Comment: It looks exactly like on tablet and any other mobile device. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

(As Ashwin K pointed out) - In Chrome, press F12 and hit the Phone Icon. You can change the device type from the dropdown at the top of the page.

In Edge & Internet Explorer (v11), press F12 and select Emulation. Can't currently vouch for versions below 11.

In Safari, use the Develop menu at the top of the page (enable in Safari's preferences if it's not there)

In Firefox,  Ctrl+Shift+M or Cmd+Opt+M if you're using a Mac